# Get replied messages

Tags: python, parsing, telegram, telethon

I wrote a program using **Python** and **telethon**, and I need to get all replied messages from one message.

But at the moment the code gets only one replied message.

```py
import json
import os

from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty, Message
from .parser import Parser
from .converter import Converter


class TelegramBot:
    def __init__(self, api_id: int, api_hash: str, search_data: dict[str, str], client):
        self.api_id = api_id
        self.api_hash = api_hash
        self.message_data = []
        self.search_data = search_data
        self.client = client

    def get_mess(self):
        messages = self.client.iter_messages(self.search_data["channel_name"],
                                             search=self.search_data["searching_word"])

        for message in messages:
            # Declare classes
            parser = Parser()
            converter = Converter()

            # Convert channel link
            channel_link = parser.parse_link(self.search_data["channel_name"], self.client)
            link = f"{channel_link}/{message.id}" if message.id else None

            # Get some fields
            date = message.date.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
            sender = message.get_sender()
            converted_message = converter.convert_message(message) if message.message else None
            message_base = {
                "message": converted_message,
                "date": date,
                "id": message.id if message.id and message else None,
                "username": sender.username if sender and sender.username else None,
                "first_name": sender.first_name if sender and sender.username else None,
                "last_name": sender.last_name if sender and sender.last_name else None,
                "link": link,
            }
            if message.reply_to is None:
                self.__add_message_without_reply(message_base)
            else:
                self.__add_message_with_reply(message, channel_link, message_base)

    def __get_replied_message(self, message, channel_link):
        if not message:
            return None

        converter = Converter()
        converted_message = converter.convert_message(message)
        repl_mess_sender = message.get_sender()
        replied_message_date = message.date.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")

        replied_message_data = {
            "message": converted_message,
            "date": replied_message_date,
            "username": repl_mess_sender.username if repl_mess_sender and repl_mess_sender.username else None,
            "first_name": repl_mess_sender.first_name if repl_mess_sender and repl_mess_sender.first_name else None,
            "last_name": repl_mess_sender.last_name if repl_mess_sender and repl_mess_sender.last_name else None,
            "link": f"{channel_link}/{message.id}" if message.id else None,
            "replied_message": self.__get_replied_message(message.get_reply_message(), channel_link),
        }

        return replied_message_data

    def __add_message_with_reply(self, message, channel_link, message_base):
        try:
            replied_message = self.__get_replied_message(message.get_reply_message(), channel_link)
            message_base["replied_message"] = replied_message
            self.message_data.append(message_base)
            print(f"Add message with reply. Message id: {message_base['id']}")

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error adding message with reply: {e}. Message id: {message_base['id']}")

    def __add_message_without_reply(self, message_base):
        id = message_base["id"]
        try:
            message_base["replied_message"] = None
            self.message_data.append(message_base)
            print(f"Add message without reply. Message id: {id}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error adding message without reply: {e}. Message id: {id}")

    def add_to_file(self):
        try:
            if len(self.message_data) == 0:
                print("Data is empty")
                return
            print("Adding to file...")
            desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), 'Desktop')
            main_dir_path = os.path.join(desktop_path, 'messages')
            dir_path = os.path.join(main_dir_path, self.search_data["channel_name"])
            file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, f'{self.search_data["searching_word"]}.json')

            os.makedirs(dir_path, exist_ok=True)
            with open(file_path, 'w',
                      encoding='utf8') as f:
                json_data = json.dumps(self.message_data, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
                f.write(json_data)
            print("All is completed successfully!")
            return f"Check the {file_path}"
        except Exception as e:
            return f"Error adding to file: {e}"
```

Method for message `get_reply_message()` returns one message, but when I review this at telegram I found more messages

I tried to add replied message to an array but I always get one replied message instead of 5 or 2

The not working method is `__add_message_with_reply`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello Kolia, did you solve your problem?